# Unable to print variables' attributes in html using jinja2

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to print attributes of a variable using jinja2 in html.

```
            {% for kk in resp['_source']['IDENTITY, PURITY AND STRENGTH'] %}
           <br> <b> {{kk}} : </b> resp['_source']['IDENTITY, PURITY AND STRENGTH']['{{kk}}']  <br>
                {{resp['_source']['IDENTITY, PURITY AND STRENGTH'].kk}}
            {% endfor %}
```

I want to print the content of **resp['_source']['IDENTITY, PURITY AND STRENGTH']['kk']** where kk itself is an attribute of **resp['_source']['IDENTITY, PURITY AND STRENGTH']**.
To do the aforementioned task i tried 2 methods (shown in line 2 and line 3 of the code).
While line 2 gives output

```
Foreign matter : resp['_source']['IDENTITY, PURITY AND STRENGTH']['Foreign matter']
```

when the value of kk is "Foreign matter". Line 3 doesn't print anything whatsoever.